# How to uninstall Sencha Cmd v6.0.0.202 from Mac?

Tags: macos, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

As I need to deal with the previous versions of Sencha, I am planning to remove the latest version of 'Sencha Cmd' on Mac 10.9.5. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installs under `/Users/<username>/bin/Sencha/Cmd/<version>/` and doesn't remove previous versions from the `Cmd` directory - which by the sound of your post means you will likely still have your previous **5.x** available.

Typically, the install adds the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file which you will want to double check and make sure that the version in the shell path matches the old version you wish to use:

```
export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/<username>/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.x.x.x"
export PATH=/Users/<username>/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.x.x.x:$PATH
```

That said, I noticed with Sencha 6 that a symbolic link named `sencha` was introduced in the `~/bin/Sencha/Cmd` directory - presumably to avoid polluting your bash configuration in future versions.  You may need to rename or remove this to avoid conflict.

Lastly re-source / restart your terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

(I am using macOS 10.12.5, Sencha 6.2.2.36)

Run command

```
cd /Users/your_user_name/bin
rm -rf Sencha
```

Answer (score 1):

Ladysign have written a blog about this. You can perfectly run two versions together:

> Running multiple Cmd versions side by side
>
> Something else I did. What you might consider to setup as well,
>   especially in case you are developing Sencha Touch, Ext JS 6, and / or
>   Ext JS 4 & 5 apps all together... Is making earlier Sencha Cmd
>   versions available on the command -line.
>
> When I type sencha5, I run Sencha Cmd 5 commands. When I type sencha,
>   I run the latest Cmd 6 commands. That's because I bound these to the
>   correct paths. You can do this too. It's very easy.
>
> First of all make sure the paths to the earlier versions are in the
>   .bash_profile / environment vars. (which you probably already did,
>   since I wrote it above). Second, and the most important step, is
>   renaming the sencha executable (located in the Cmd installation
>   folder) to sencha5, sencha4 etc.

Source: http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/running-multiple-sencha-cmd-versions-for-example-to-support-sencha-architect/